# ¿Cómo apuntar a una variable en Excel desde VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

¿Cómo apuntar a una variable en Excel desde VBA que no sea por coordenada (Range)?
o referenciar el campo de una tabla.

Ya que aveces elimino o corro celdas y se pierde la referencia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede Guardar la variable con **Definir Nombre** en la ficha **Formulas**

Ejemplo: La celda `G11` con el nombre `Valor`

Luego lo puede llamar en VBA con `Range("Valor").Value` no importa las celdas o columnas que se eliminen siempre conservara ese valor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quiero decir es que si utilizas "Definir Nombre en la ficha Formulas" y eliminas la columna o la fila donde has hecho esa referencia, esta se perderá y obtendrás un mensaje de error al volver a referenciarla. Solo funciona si desplazas la celda y Nicolás ha mencionado que "aveces elimino o corro celdas y se pierde la referencia".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro método que funciona en todos los casos (comprobado) es automatizar el refresco de la celda. Cuando Excel se cierra la celda de referencia se guardará y al volver a abrir la hoja, ese valor se recuperará en V_TMP. Esta variable temporal está ahí para asegurar el dato que no quieres perder. El resto de líneas complementan el correcto funcionamiento del codigo. Obviamente, si eliminamos esta fila o columna, todas las celdas que estuvieran referenciadas a esta mostrarán un #¡REF!

Para evitar eso podemos actualizar las celdas comprometidas insertando su formula nuevamente con un Range("B1").Formula = "=1000*A1", por ejemplo.

Incluye en el objeto "ThisWorkBook" las siguientes líneas:

```
Public V_TMP

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    V_TMP = Range("A1")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo error1
    If Target <> Range("A1") Then
        Range("A1") = V_TMP
    Else
        V_TMP = Range("A1")
    End If
    Exit Sub

error1:
    Range("A1") = V_TMP
    Range("B1").Formula = "=1000*A1"    'Refresca la celda comprometida
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera más limpia de hacer referencia desde VBA a variables de un libro es mediante [Mivariable], es decir, usar desde VBA el nombre de la variable entre corchetes. El ámbito de la misma dependerá de la fórmula.
Evidentemente, si eliminas la celda a la que hace referencia...dará un error #¡REF!